# Managing multiple TCP connections on android to one port

Tags: android, tcp

I'm creating an android library which contains a service that establishes a TCP connection to a specific port. While this works fine when only one app is running, if multiple apps using the service are running it obviously throws a Bind Exception.

Is it possible for the applications to share the service and both receive the data or is it simply possible for both of them to share a port?

Comment: you will have to use threading where the each new request will be serviced by a new thread

Comment: It sounds more like you're writing a library that establishes a *listening socket*. Otherwise you wouldn't be doing  a bind at all. Please clarify.